# How to pass multiple inputs in Keras?

Tags: neural-network, keras

I would like to compare images with custom model. So, I have model with 2 inputs.

How to feed two inputs for train and validation?

If I do

```
self.classifier.fit([x1_train, x2_train], y_train,
                                batch_size=batch_size,
                                epochs=epochs,
                                verbose=1,
                                validation_data=([x1_valid, x2_valid], y_valid),
                                shuffle=True)
```

it complains

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: What are your inputs like? It seems to be that your inputs are not `ndarray`.

Comment: @danche don't think so; I think the error is due to `[x1_train, x2_train]` being a list instead of `ndarray`.

Comment: @desertnaut I was thinking this way too, but @danche was right; after I made all of `x` to be `ndarray`-s, model ate inputs successfully.

Comment: @desertnaut Keras limited the multiple inputs into `list` format..